# Usage of "appreciate your assistance/help for ~ing"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I would like to ask you all whether it is grammatically correct to use "appreciate your assistance/help **for ~ing**".

And I am confused with the **order** of "someone" and "me" in the expression of "**put ~ in touch with ~**" to thank someone who introduced me a new person.

I appreciate your kind assistance for putting **me** in touch with **someone**.

Or
I appreciate your kind assistance for putting **someone** in touch with **me**.

Or 
are they both wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your first question, you do not need the **for**. Examples:

*I appreciate your assistance filling out the form.*

*I appreciate your assistance finding a job.*

*I appreciate your help cleaning the garage.*

Or for a simpler case like the exact one you posted, 
*I appreciate your assistance moving.*

If for some reason you really want a conjunction there, you could use **in** for many cases, but it's not necessary. However, it's worth knowing as many people use it. Example: *Thank you for your help in cooking dinner.*

In the second question, the order of someone vs. me will depend on what you're trying to convey.

`someone in touch with me` implies the person you are speaking to told this `someone` your information and that someone contacted you. `me in touch with someone` is the reverse: the person you are speaking to gave you the `someone`'s information and you contacted this someone.

It's all about who contacted who: **X** put **Y** in touch with **Z**. To put it another way: **X** enabled **Y** contacting **Z**. **X** is implicitly the person you are speaking to, ie, *"you"*.

Comment: Hi William Kappler, in `Thank you for your help in cooking dinner`, is `cooking dinner` a gerund phrase? What if I change the sentence to `Thank you for your help in letting me cook dinner`, is `letting me cook dinner` still a gerund phrase? Thanks!